# Intel FFT performance

Tags: performance, benchmarking, fft, sse

What processor will perform better, [i5-2500K](http://ark.intel.com/products/52210) or [i7-960](http://ark.intel.com/products/37151), regarding certain FFT operations per second, for example: complex FFT in-place on 16k buffer length?

I am asking that because I would like to saturate all cores and all threads, and since i7 has 8 threads and i5 only 4, my main concern is if the SSE instructions are able to run in parallel on all 8 logical threads.

Comment: From benchmarking I've done on 2D FFTs it looks like FFTW easily beats the Intel FFT. YMMV of course.

Comment: @Paul - we are waging wars between two processors, not two libraries :)

Comment: Yes, but if you are actually wanting to get maximum performance then you can't ignore the choice of library.

Comment: @Paul - yeah, I'll probably go for custom tailored ASM solution for the FINAL stuff.

Comment: I doubt that it will be as fast as FFTW - it's pretty hard to beat.

Comment: I would be able to take some problem-domain specific optimization, and I expect to harness some cycles from that direction.

Comment: Daniel Mošmondor, can you program AVX in asm manually?

Comment: Daniel Mošmondor, it is hard. Also, FFTW and Intel's MKL are very fast and not every programmer can beat them in asm.

Comment: @osgx I ended up using fftw, of course.  nothing else comes even close to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This test http://ixbtlabs.com/articles3/cpu/ci7-turbo-ht-p1.html?pages=ci7-turbo-ht-p1.html

shows that gain from turning on the HT on i7 was 0% for FFT. (Scientific applications table, line FFT). The FFT was from MATLAB ( based on a library called FFTW).

i7-960 has 4 cores and 8 threads is from HyperThreading (HT). As was shown by ixbt, HT will not help to compute more FFTs, so I recommend you to buy newer i5-2500 with same 4 cores, but greater freq, greater turbo boost (dynamic overclocking) and newer technology.

Also, this 'i5' is of next microarchitecture (SNB - Sandy Bridge) and it has an AVX (twice a lot FLOPS per GHz). If FFT can use it (use modern library and modern compiler), it should almost **double FFT performance** (if we will not consider the memory bw limits). Intel says, there is 1.8x grow from AVX in their newer MKL: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-avx-optimization-in-intel-mkl-v103/

> The AVX/NHM (an AVX-enabled over Nehalem NHM) speedup is 1.8x for radix-2 1D CFFTs with N=1024

So, the i5-2500 is 1.8x better per tick from AVX, it has a bit more GHz (both from spec and TurboBoost) and it supports faster memory (DDR3-1066 for NHM and DDR3-1333 for i5 SND).

Comment: 0% gain is due to the fact that there are still only 4 physical FPU's with 8 threads contending for them. With math heavy calculations I/O context switching on the 2 threads that would normally happen, never does so it acts just like a quad core under max load.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, one of the things about the i7 having 8 threads is that during context switches (which will happen more often because of the logical cores) FPU state is NOT PRESERVED so that means once an FPU operation resumes it has to repopulate the FPU structures so that it can complete the operation. From what I can tell the i5-2500k will do this faster since the threads only contend per core instead of a higher contention rate to use the FPU (which there are only 4 of).

P.S : I could possibly be wrong since I'm not sure on the specifics of the 960 but this is what I've found from some of the work I've done in the past.

Comment: Is someone could back this up with a benchmark, that would be GREAT.  thanks for offering me a way to not waste money to get nothing.

Comment: i7-960 gets 6676 on PassMark, 7263 for i5-2500k

Comment: Looks like the i5-2500k will outdo it, let me see if I can find a LinPack test run

Comment: THANKS.  If you could supply the info for particular fft case (bench) that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm going on raw FPU performance here, and I can't seem to find any benchmarks for FFT or FFTW.